# .NET Application which launches command at a particular time

Tags: c#, .net, scheduling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Run windows service task at a specific time using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5793011/run-windows-service-task-at-a-specific-time-using-c-sharp)

I am building an app in .NET (c#). I am trying to find out how to write to a log at a particular time everyday at various times I specify.

I understand I can easily do this with a scheduled task, but I would like to keep the app running (preferably a console app). And launch commands at designated times.

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681465/c-sharp-execute-function-at-specific-time

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5793011/run-windows-service-task-at-a-specific-time-using-c-sharp

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373306/how-to-execute-code-in-c-sharp-service-one-time-per-day-at-the-same-hour

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the [Quartz .NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) library. It's worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use one of the 3 [.Net Timer classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx), most likely [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx). You'd set the Timer's Interval property, and do your logging in the event handler for the Timer's Elapsed event

Answer (score -1):

If you want an application to keep running then use a Windows service but, personally, given what I know of your requirements, I'd probably just go with a scheduled task.

Windows Service : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx